# How to evaluate the performance of different model on one dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I want to evaluate the performance different model such as `SVM`, `RandForest`, `CNN` etc, I only have one dataset. So I split the dataset to training set and testing set and train different model on this dataset with training data and test with testing dataset.

Can I get the real performance of different model on only one dataset? For example: I found `SVM` model get the best result, So Should I select the SVM as my final classification model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its probably a better idea to cross validate your models with different test samples through cross validation to avoid biases. Also check your models against different evaluation metrics depending upon your application type. For instance use recall, accuracy and AUC for each model if its a classification problem.

Evaluation results can be pretty deceptive and require extensive validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can Plot ROC curve for all the models.The model for which AUC is highest will be best model.